# Using Cargo.lock to effectively manage & pull dependency versions in my crates

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My workspace looks like this:

```
workspace
     |--other_crate <== existing crate relying on tokio
         |-- Cargo.toml
     |--my_crate <== this is a new crate called using "cargo new --lib"
         |-- Cargo.toml
     |--Cargo.lock
     |--Cargo.toml
```

I want to add this dependency from Cargo.lock in my new crate:

```
[[package]]
name = "tokio"
version = "1.14.1"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "b9d0183f6f6001549ab68f8c7585093bb732beefbcf6d23a10b9b95c73a1dd49"
dependencies = [
...
]
```

I would like my_crate to always rely on the same tokio version as other_crate, what is the best way to do it? I am guessing Cargo.lock is the solution to do this, but there is not much documentation on how to do so. In other words, is there a solution something like this in my_crate/Cargo.toml:

```
...
[dependencies]
tokio = {// refer to Cargo.lock's tokio entry and use it}
...
```

Currently, I just manually looking up Cargo.lock's entry and manually copying the version. However, if I have N crates relying on the same entry, ensuring that there is version consistency (whenever Cargo.lock needs to be updated) will be backbreaking work...

Comment: Why do you want such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel there's a few misunderstandings here.

First, `Cargo.toml` is the authoritive description of your package. The `Cargo.lock` is purely supplemental. Thus there's not a mechanism to defer to the latter; if it could, there would be a circular logic where the `.toml` relies on something from the lockfile, but the lockfile needs the `.toml` to work. Imagine if you wanted to regenerate the lockfile in your scenario, there'd be no basis for what version the tokio dependency should be.

Second, `Cargo.lock` already ensures a single version is used for compatible dependencies. If one crate depends on tokio 1.12, but another depends on 1.14, the `Cargo.lock` will only contain a single tokio 1.x entry that is compatible with both. Two crates could have completely separate dependency versions and thus have two entries for tokio in `Cargo.lock`, but only if they are semver incompatible (0.1 vs 1.x vs 2.x).

Thirdly, there is not a way to depend on another crate's dependencies. They are not considered part of a crate's public interface for determining breaking changes (unless of course they are publically exposed). A crate should be free to update internal-only dependencies without worry of breaking another.

---

That being said, there is a mechanism that would accomplish this: [workspace dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#the-dependencies-table). Within a workspace, you can allow crates to defer to a single source of truth for their dependencies by putting them in your root workspace's `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
# workspace/Cargo.toml
[workspace.dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.14.1" }
```

```toml
# workspace/other_crate/Cargo.toml and
# workspace/my_crate/Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { workspace = true }
```